# What is the maximal pot bet if one of the players has less chips than minimum raise

Tags: pot-limit

Assuming 3 players in a pot limit game.

Dealer has 1000$ in chips
SB has 1000$ in chips
BB has 100$ in chips

blinds are 100/200

SB puts 100, BB is all in with 100 (instead of 200).

if Dealer wants to raise the pot; is it calculated according to 200$ as in the pot or according to 300$ (as should be if BB had the required amount)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pot limit games when a bet is outstanding, the amount you can raise by is calculated after your call of the existing bet is added to the pot. Here, the current pot is 200. It doesn't matter that the BB would have paid more if he had more - the amount of a pot-sized bet is based on the size of the pot.

Add dealer's call of the current bet, which is another 200. Thus dealer can raise another 400, to a total bet of 600.

Answer (score 0):

It is calculated as if the BB has put in his full amount. So the minimum raise would be $400.

Comment: as much as I know, in that case the pot bet is 700.
blinds are 100/200. minimum raise is 400 --> 100+200+400=700.